# Initctl missing, need to run reload-configuration command

Tags: upstart

Ubuntu Sever, 18.04

I have a situation where I need to run a configuration file. The instructions call for me to run the following command:
      initctl reload-configuration

However, initctl doesn't exist on my system.
I have tried installing upstart via apt-get but it failed and told me that the package was unavailable and recommended a different package.

Package upstart is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  systemd-sysv

I installed this package ( systemd-sysv )

But when I tried to run the initclt reload-configuration command it still failed. I did some additional research here about the difference between service vs initctl.

I tried to run service reload-configuration but that didn't work because it doesn't know what the reload-configuration was.

Can someone tell me what else I can do to get this new config file to be acted upon?

Thanks

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Ubuntu replaced Upstart with systemd ~5 years ago. No upstart commands are supported in any current release.